# Отображение приложения на разных OS

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть ли какой то способ, для того что бы приложения на WinForms или WPF начиная с XP и дальше до 10, выглядели одинаково? Есть иногда даже разница между 7 и 10 виндой.

Comment: Или нету какого то общего способа это сделать и все надо вручную изменять для каждой винды?

Comment: Вам нужно прям попиксельное совпадение отображения что ли? Потому как одинаково оно выглядит, относительно.

Comment: Да, прям 1 в 1. Такое возможно сделать без особого гемороя?

Comment: Без геморроя - точно нет. Лучше скажите, что конкретно не устраивает, может окажется что всё мелочи.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Смотрите.

Фреймворк WPF содержит несколько *тем*, каждая из которых соответствует определённому стилю UI. Эти темы содержатся в общедоступных сборках, и имеют название `PresentationFramework.*.dll`.

Вы должны просто подключить эти темы в ваше приложение, и они будут применены. Например, если вы хотите, чтобы всё приложение имело стиль Aero, как в Windows 7, вы должны сделать следующее: (1) подключить в References сборку `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`, и (2) подключить стили в вашем `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero,
                                         Version=4.0.0.0,
                                         Culture=neutral,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                                ;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Аналогично, вы можете подключить сборку PresentationFramework.Classic.dll и стили

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic,
                                         Version=4.0.0.0,
                                         Culture=neutral,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                                ;component/themes/Classic.xaml"/>
```

чтобы получить визуальный стиль как в «классическом» стиле Windows XP (имитация Windows 2000).

В PresentationFramework.Luna.dll есть несколько тем:

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna,
                                         Version=4.0.0.0,
                                         Culture=neutral,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                                ;component/themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml"/>
```

— стандартная тема Windows XP,

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna,
                                         Version=4.0.0.0,
                                         Culture=neutral,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                                ;component/themes/Luna.Metallic.xaml"/>
```

— тема XP Silver (Metallic),

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna,
                                         Version=4.0.0.0,
                                         Culture=neutral,
                                         PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                                ;component/themes/Luna.Homestead.xaml"/>
```

— зелёная тема XP Homestead.

В PresentationFramework.Royale.dll

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Royale,
                                 Version=4.0.0.0,
                                 Culture=neutral,
                                 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                        ;component/themes/Royale.NormalColor.xaml"/>
```

— тема XP Media Center Edition и т. д.

Если вы хотите вид как в Window 8/10, вам понадобится PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll и/или PresentationFramework.AeroLite.dll. Они доступны только на старших версиях Windows, так что для использования на младших вам придётся установить флажок CopyLocal и таскать сборки в комплекте. В них идёт по одной теме:

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero2,
                                 Version=4.0.0.0,
                                 Culture=neutral,
                                 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                        ;component/themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml"/>
```

и

```
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.AeroLite,
                                 Version=4.0.0.0,
                                 Culture=neutral,
                                 PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                        ;component/themes/AeroLite.NormalColor.xaml"/>
```

Вы можете, кстати, определять стили локально, тогда только этот кусок приложения будет соответствовать вашей теме. Например:

[image: Много кнопок]

PublicKeyToken, [судя по всему](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Windows.Themes), всегда один и тот же.

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [Как установить в WPF стиль Windows 7 на XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2075720/276994)
- [Системная сборка с темой не находится во время выполнения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185946/276994)
- [Как правильно стилизовать собственные контролы, если приложение использует одну из системных тем?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4239714/276994)